# How can I set user-agent in IOWebSocketChannel?

Tags: dart, websocket, dart-io

I work with [IOWebSocketChannel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) and I don't have access to `Webscoket` inside it
in order to change the [user-agent](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-io/WebSocket/userAgent.html). how can I achieve that and set `user agent` for `IOWebSocketChannel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this issue:  [Add option to set User Agent for Websocket #32008](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32008)
and the documentation: [WebSocket](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-io/WebSocket/userAgent.html)

you can't set user agent for IOWebSocketChannel but you can just set userAgent for all Websocket instance by call:

```
Websocket.userAgent = 'your desired agent';
```

this works for all Websocket instance, so there is no need to access the websocket instance object passed to IOWebSocketChannel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the socket using [IOWebSocketChannel.connect](https://pub.dev/documentation/web_socket_channel/latest/web_socket_channel.io/IOWebSocketChannel/IOWebSocketChannel.connect.html) you can just add the user-agent in the headers parameter, or otherwise if you are upgrading to a IOWebSocketChannel from a `WebSocket` (with [WebSocket.connect](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/WebSocket/connect.html)) set your headers there.

Comment: thanks for the response, it appears to add user-agent to the header doesn't override user-aget and just add another one to the header.

Comment: What is the other other user agent? And how are you adding it? You can have two user agent on the same request